# Android detect record event of camera

Tags: android, camera

Is there a way to detect whether recording has started or not in android camera video?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not for that `Intent` structure.

If you include `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, indicating where the video should be recorded, in theory you could watch to see when bytes are starting to get written to that file.

Comment: i tired it but u cant do that cause the file will not be created until you have done recording the video

Comment: @kautilyahari: That behavior may depend on the camera app. But, other than monitoring the file for changes, you have no options.